# What is the fire resistance on a corrugated iron wall?

Tags: walls, fireproof

I have a timber stud frame extension with external corrugated iron cladding.  Can anyone give me any information about the fire resistance?  The construction is :
- Corrugated iron (pe-painted about 1mm thick -)
- battens
- building paper
- OSB (weather-proof chip board)
- 150mm timber frame with Celotex insulation between stud work.
- vapour barrier
- 2 sheets of 12.5mm fire retardant plaster board
Thanks
Stephen

Comment: Are you asking for the combined total fire *rating* (usually expressed in hours) for the wall assembly? In the US, 1 layer of 15.9mm (5/8") fire-resistive gypsum wall board will give a "1-hour" fire rating to a properly constructed wall assembly. You could probably get resistance specs for various wall assemblies from your "plaster board trade council"; check out this link: http://www.gypsum.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Fire_Safety_Information.pdf

Comment: The building inspector is happy that there is 1 hour fire resistance from the inside, but as the external wall is wishing 1metre of the boundary, he needs to know that there would be one hour resistance from an external fire source.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition tells me the exterior would not provide "1-hour" fire protection. Although the metal cladding certainly would not *burn*, it will readily conduct heat.
The gypsum/plaster-board is a very poor heat transfer medium and that along with the fire-resistant paper on it is what gives it it's fire rating.

You should start to think about maybe stucco or plaster over the cladding (yes, it can be done) which if properly applied would be great for fire protection (although rating it would be a guess). Or removing the cladding and adding a layer of the plaster board behind it.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems that a fire-resistant paint would be acceptable to the building officer, so this seems a reasonably simple and cost effective solution.